# How to insert a line in a file between two blocks of known lines (if not already inserted previously), using bash?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, file-manipulation

I wrote a bash script which can modify php.ini according to my needs.
Now I have to introduce a new change, and I cannot find a clear solution to it.

I need to modify php.ini in order to insert (if not already inserted previously)

```
extension="memcache.so"
```

between the block

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

and the block

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

possibly just before the second one.
Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance

**EDITED: solved by using**

```
if ! grep -Fxq 'extension="memcache.so"' 'php.ini'; then
    line=$(cat 'php.ini' | grep -n '; Module Settings ;' | grep -o '^[0-9]*')
    line=$((line - 2))
    sudo sed -i ${line}'i\extension="memcache.so"' 'php.ini'
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the line number using `grep -n`:

```
line=$(cat php.ini | grep -n 'Module Settings' | grep -o '^[0-9]*')
```

Calculate the line to insert the text to:

```
line=$((line - 3))
```

Insert it using sed or awk. Examples to insert "newline" on line 45:

```
sed '45i\newline' file
awk 'NR==45{print "newline"}1'
```

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/^; Dynamic Extensions ;$/,/^; Module Settings ;$/{H;//{x;/extension="memcache.so"/{p;d};/;;;\n/{s//&extension="memcache.so"\n/p}};d}' file
```

This will insert `extension="memcache.so"` between `; Dynamic Extensions ;` and `; Module Settings ;` unless `extension="memcache.so"` is already present.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Anyhow, in this specific example, I need to add `extension="memcache.so"` unless the same extension hasn't been added before ... other extensions might be (and actually are) present.

Comment: I think you mean "... _if_ the same extension hasn't been added before". Have amended the solution to reflect your comment.

Comment: sorry! Yes: that what I meant :) .. your code now is adding `extension="memcache.so"` all the times even if already present ..

Comment: Cut-n-paste caught me out! Had an extra `=`. Solution amended

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following sed script:

```
/^;\+$/{
N
/^;\+\n; Module Settings ;$/i extension="memcache.so"
}
```

Basically it matches these lines:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
```

and inserts before them the desired string (`extension="memcache.so"`)

Comment: sorry, I can't understand how to use your suggestion. Which would be the command to fire?

Comment: @LucaBorrione Save the script in a file and execute `sed -f <script.sed> php.ini`. This will print to stdout, if you want to make the changes in place, use also `-i`.

Comment: Thank you it's working fine. Never done such a thing before. One never stops to learn. A great thank!