# How to insert a line just after the first regex match with sed?

Tags: bash, file-io, sed

I have a few `CmakeLists.txt` files and I would like to insert another include right after a known include.  So, here's what I've got:

```
include_directories(src include)
```

And, here's what I would like to end up with

```
include_directories(src include)
include_directories("${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include")
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this? I'm assuming `sed` would make the most sense, but I'm open to alternatives.

[edit] Found a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8971314/86263).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple sed command with inline editing:

```
sed -i.bak '/include_directories(src include)/a\
include_directories("${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include")
' CmakeLists.txt
```

- This uses `a` command which appends a new string after searched string.
- `-i.bak` is for incline editing of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not satisfied with the answer to the duplicate question, you could try this:

```
sed '/include_directories(src include)/s/$/\
include_directories(\"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}\/include\")/' filename
```

This might or not work, depending on your shell. If it doesn't, the lesson is to attempt simple things first, then build up.

Answer (score 0):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else you're better off with awk:

```
awk '{print} /include_directories\(src include\)/{print "include_directories(\"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include\")"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` variation:

```
awk '/include_directories\(src include\)/{$0=$0 "\ninclude_directories(\"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include\")"}8' file
```

If pattern found, add a new line to current line, then print all.