# Write output of command to specific line

Tags: bash, sed, cat

I need to write the output of a command to a specific line in a document. I can not just append it like so `COMMAND | cat >> file`, I need it to be added between two lines without replacing one or the other. I'm sure you must be able to do this via sed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971314/how-to-insert-a-line-in-a-file-between-two-blocks-of-known-lines-if-not-already

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add text between two patterns in File using sed command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836306/add-text-between-two-patterns-in-file-using-sed-command)

Answer (score 2):

The following solution works when the output of `COMMAND` is only 1 line (inserting to line 4):

```
COMMAND | sed -i "4i \`cat` FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use that command:

```
command | sed -i '3r /dev/stdin' file
```

That inserts text after the 3rd line and reads from stdin (all output from `command`).