# SED command line utility (for Windows): How to add a new text line after specified line

Tags: shell, sed, scripting, ini

Please give me suggestion. I need a working solution for **sed.exe** command line utility (SED build **for Windows**, version 4.1.5.4013). Or just give me a working UNIX-solution and i'll try to adapt it for my sed (for Win OS).

How to add the new (pretty sophisticated, to be honest) text line after specified line in a text file?

I have input file that contains following text (two lines):

```
[Pagebar Item Popup Menu]
Feature !Private, Item, MI_IDM_MENU_PAGEBAR_NEW_PAGE    = New Page, 1,,,"New item menu"
```

I need to insert following line between first and second lines (above mentioned ):

```
Item, "Load tab" = Enable Javascript,,,,"Remove from Start Page.rtl" & Enable   plugins & Enable display images & Reload
```

Is it possible to replace(but not to add new line every time when sed's command running!) an existing first line with two lines (replaced line + the new added string). Or, for an example, to make check if "**Item, "Load tab".....**" line already exists, avoid undesirable duplicates of the new line which is being inserted?

What I've tried but it didn't work:

```
sed -i "s/"\[Pagebar Item Popup Menu\]"/"\[Pagebar Item Popup Menu\]"\n"^Item,"Load tab"=Enable Javascript,,,,"Remove from Start Page\.rtl" & Enable plugins & Enable display images & Reload[ 0-9]\{1,\}[.,][0-9]\{3\}$/g" standard_menu.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e "/pattern/ {p;s/.*/line_to_insert/;}" input_file > output_file
```

When pattern matches sed will do the following:

1. p: print pattern space: in this case this is the matching line
2. s/.*/line_to_insert/: changes pattern space to line_to_insert

If sed was called without -n then pattern space will be written out

If sed was called with -n then an additional p; command will be needed:

```
sed -e "/pattern/ {p;s/.*/line_to_insert/;p;}" input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

For a unix solution under windows have you considered cygwin?

https://www.cygwin.com/

Secondly, your sed command looks a bit funky - have you tried making it easier on the eyes by using a different set of quotes to surround the expression?

finally, I think you might want cygwin as I don't believe sed alone will do what you want.

[How to insert a line in a file between two blocks of known lines (if not already inserted previously), using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971314/how-to-insert-a-line-in-a-file-between-two-blocks-of-known-lines-if-not-already)

This example uses grep as well

Thanks,

//P